# Aptana PHP Formatter - use custom formatting rules

Tags: php, formatting, format, aptana

I'm using Apatana's formatting features in PHP documents, it works well except with arrays where it transform this:

```
$data = array(
    'email' => $params['email'],
    'username' => $params['username'],
);
```

into this:

```
$data = array('email' => $params['email'], 'username' => $params['username']);
```

is there a way to avoid this and set custom formatting rules?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. There is a way.

Go to the Studio's preferences and locate the 'Formatter' item. If you are using the default formatter profile, create a new one by clicking the '+' icon.

Click to edit the PHP formatting setting (double-click the 'PHP' item, or click it and than click the 'Edit' button).

Under the 'New Lines' tab, check the option to 'Insert new line between array-creation elements'. OK the dialogs. Make sure that the profile you just created is the selected one in the formatter preferences page, and format your code.

Cheers